# How to compute angle between a line and a plane in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, vector

Five points `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` are given in ℝ³. How do I compute the angle between the line `D-E` and the plane defined by `A`, `B`, and `C`?

I understand the question but I don't know how to program it in MATLAB. I'm new to MATLAB so detailed information would be very helpful. This what I have tried, but it's giving me wrong output:

```
point1 = cross(B-A, C-A);
point2 = cross(D, E);
point3 = cross(point1, point2);
point4 = sqrt(A.*A + B.*B + C.*C);
point5 = sqrt(D.*D + E.*E)

point6 = point4*point5;
final  = point3 / point6
```

Comment: Variable names cannot contain spaces. `point 1`, for example, should be named `point1`.

Comment: Do you understand the math of this problem? if you got the math right, it's actually not that difficult. I think, you got the math wrong!

Comment: same goes for `square root` - how about some matlab tutorials first?

Comment: The spaces were because of trying to post to stack overflow require you to put it in away people understand. Thanks though.

Comment: my 0.02$: it's not really stack overflow that requires you to put it in a way that people understand, it's called courtesy. After all, you want people to help you - how can someone without understanding help?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain your logic? Because what you tried makes no sense to me...

Comment: Was trying to use dot product to find the angle.

Comment: I did not know how to set it up in matlab so i tried to recreate it by you math as close as possible. I would like to thank you been working on find out how to use matlab and solve this for 5 hours.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis thanks that was a huge help.

Comment: I would vote up but i am new to stack as well. But thanks

Comment: In the future, edit [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122580/trying-to-find-the-angles-of-two-planes) rather than posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
%// normal vector to plane ABC
N = cross(B-A, C-A);

%// angle between plane and line, equals pi/2 - angle between D-E and N
alpha = abs( pi/2 - acos( dot(E-D, N)/norm(N)/norm(E-D) ) );

%// you probably want it in degrees: 
alpha = rad2deg(alpha);
```